# executing html code through xsl param in xml

Tags: html, xslt, wso2-esb

I'm trying to pass some html tags as the value of my `xsl:param name="messageBody"` to get executed before generating my template. But instead of executing the html code, they are displayed as text.

This is when I am generating a template with the WSO2 ESB.  Once used `xsl:value-of select="$messageBody"` but displayed the html text instead of executing and the same for `xsl:copy-of select="$messageBody"`

Below is code fragment that which include the value of that `xsl:param name="messageBody"`

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="8px" cellspacing="10" style= "width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); color:#000000" align= "center">
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="microservicerows">
            <th>Target Account</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="$messageBody"/>                                                         
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The expected output should be displaying new table rows under the header tags but instead the it's just plain text once my template is generated.

The value of the `xsl:param name="messageBody"` is below

```
<tr class="microservicerows">
    <td>1000029061</td>
    <td>55,000.00</td>
    <td>Unsuccessful</td>
    <td>My target</td>
    <td>02/09/2019</td>
</tr> 
    <tr class="microservicerows">
    <td>1000029078</td>
    <td>900.00</td>
    <td>Successful</td>
    <td>Start later</td>
    <td>03/09/2019</td>
</tr>]
```

Comment: Please edit your question in order to be more clear for us to answer.

Comment: sorry...is this better?

Comment: Fixed that problem for you :)

Comment: thanks for that but any hints for the solution